# apply Darboux’s Theorem into a function

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I know  Darboux’s Theorem is:

> Let I be an open interval, and let $f : I \to R$ be a differentiable function. If $a, b$ are points of $I$ with $a < b$ and if $y$ lies between $f' (a)$ and $f' (b),$ then there exists a number $x \in [a, b]$ such that $f'(x) = y.$

But how can I apply that into the following question?

Deﬁine a function by
$$g(x) =\begin{cases}x &x < 1\\ x − 1 &x\geq 1
\end{cases}$$
Prove that there does not exist a function $f(x)$ that is differentiable on all of $\mathbb R$ such that $f'(x) = g(x).$

Comment: Does $g$ have the intermediate value property?

Comment: yes,it does have a IVY

Comment: Not IVY ,it's IVT

Comment: Can you prove that?

Comment: I think I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $g(-\frac12)=-\frac12$ and $g(0)=-1$, yet there does not exist $x\in(-\frac12,0)$ such that $g(x)=-\frac34$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $g(x)-x$ instead. Then you can apply Darboux's theorem.

---

Here is a detailed proof. Put $G(x)=g(x)-x$. Then
\begin{align}
G(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & x<1\\ -1& x \ge1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
By Darboux's theorem, there is no $F$ such that $F'=G$, so is $f$ such that $(f(x)-\frac{1}{2}x^2)'=G$.

Comment: can you be more specific?thanks

Comment: @Bao // Okay, so I added some detail.

Comment: Thanks for your help! U r so smart:)

Comment: @Bao you're welcome :)